# Confused About Relationship Between Number of Points and Solving Wiener Filter Coefficients in Time Domain vs Fourier Domain

Tags: filters, finite-impulse-response, wiener-filter

I'm interested in computing M, FIR filter taps / coefficients using a [Wiener](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_filter) filter approach with known signal and noise timestreams. I know of two ways to compute the coefficients: one in the Fourier domain using FFTs which is more intuitive for me and the other in the time domain using a Toeplitz covariance matrix which is more mathematical and harder for me to understand. **I'm trying to understand if there's any benefit to increasing the length of my signal or noise timestreams much beyond M points (the number of FIR taps)? Also what are the circumstances which would make one method better than the other?**  See details / problem intro below.

I have a timeseries of my expected signal and a timeseries of my noise both sampled at fs. The expected signal is generated from averaging many noisy signal timetraces which results in a noiseless expected signal timetrace. The noise is generated from averaging many PSD's of noise timetraces. The signal of interest begins at 0 and has a finite duration after which the signal returns to constant 0 but the noise time trace could be arbitrarily long.

1. Compute Filter in Fourier Space. Intuitive, FFT Approach:
   My understanding is to generate the filter coefficients from the signal and noise, I will take an M-point FFT of the averaged signal time trace and divide it by the averaged PSD of the noise time trace (ensuring the spectral resolution of the noise PSD is the same as the signal: fs/M.) The inverse FFT of that quotient will give me my M FIR taps. In this case, it doesn't seem like there's any benefit to working with more than M points of signal or noise.
2. Compute Filter in Time Domain. The other approach, *which I understand less*, is to look at noise traces longer than M points resulting in a finer spectral resolution of the noise in the average of the noise PSDs. I then take the inverse FFT of this more precise PSD and truncate the resulting timeseries to M points. The resulting truncated timeseries is used to construct a Toeplitz matrix which is used as the covariance matrix for the noise. The MxM noise covariance matrix and M-point averaged signal time trace is solved as a linear matrix equation to give the M filter taps. In this case, I'm less sure about how the length of the original, untruncated noise trace might impact performance.

In terms of which approach to use when:
I came across a note that in order for 2. to outperform 1. the original noise timetrace should be 5-10x longer than M but I'm not sure why. The only other big thing I can think of is that in both approaches the noise is assumed to be periodic but solving in the Fourier domain (method #1) also assumes the signal is periodic whereas method #2 does not make that assumption. My signal is basically periodic and it can be made to be actually periodic with a windowing function prior to taking the FFT so I'm not too concerned about this.